# Pycode environment doesn't work while the \pyc{} commands does

Tags: pythontex

I'm trying to use pythontex on Texmaker/TexLive. 
I've downloaded the pythontex package and executed the pythontex.ins file.
I've configured the compilation in this way :

```
lualatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|
/home/simon/texmf/tex/latex/pythontex/pythontex.py  %.tex|
lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

When I write :

```
\pyc{from sympy import * ;
x=Symbol('x') ;
var=latex(factor(x**2+3*x-4));
print(var)}
```

in my .tex file, I get the good result.
But as soon as I try to put all that code in a pycode environment, like :

```
\begin{pycode}
from sympy import *
x=Symbol('x')
var=latex(factor(x**2+3*x-4))
\end{pycode}
\py{var}
```

it doesn't work...

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please visit tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx and tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/.

Comment: Look at pythontex documentation pal ... There is a thourough exaplanation of that command and environment. But please, create a full MWE (with documentclass and everything), since it actually takes time to wrtite class and packages from scratch ... Try to write as last line in pycode print(var)  and after \end{pycode} add \printpythontex

Comment: Finally I did it. I don't know exactly what was wrong... But comparing with other .tex files, I rewrote mine step by step and now it works. I suppose I was wrong with some python syntax somewhere...